# How to add header icon for specific column when used ngfor for rendering the columns in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, html-table

I am trying to add the sorting feature to the application where table code is written without any specific library.

I would like to get add a sort column feature with the sorting icon.

I have achieved the sorting feature using the sort and local compare method but I am struggling to add an arrow to the specific column after the user clicks on the column.

```js
columns = ["id", "username", "test"]
assendingSort = false;
dessendingSort = false;

sortTable(param) {

    if (assendingSort) {
        sortDataDessending();
        dessendingSort = true;
    } else if () {
        sortDataAssending();
        assendingSort = true;
    } else {
        sortDataAssending();
        assendingSort = true;
    }

}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pro.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.10.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-AYmEC3Yw5cVb3ZcuHtOA93w35dYTsvhLPVnYs9eStHfGJvOvKxVfELGroGkvsg+p" crossorigin="anonymous"/>

<table>
    <thead>
    <tr>
      <th *ngFor="let col of columns" (click)="sortTable(col)">{{col}}
            <i *ngIf="assendingSort" class="fa fa-caret-up"></i>
            <i *ngIf="dessendingSort"class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
      </th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
  </table>
```